# Resize Drawable in Android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, resize, drawable

I am setting a drawable for a progress dialog (`pbarDialog`) but my issue is I want to resize the drawable each time but can't figure out how.

Here is some code:

```
Handler progressHandler = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            // some more code
            case UPDATE_PBAR:
                pbarDialog.setIcon(mAppIcon);
                pbarDialog.setMessage(mPbarMsg);
                pbarDialog.incrementProgressBy(mIncrement+1);
                break;
        }
    }
};

pbarDialog.show();

Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        // some code
        for (int i = 0; i < mApps.size(); i++) {
            mAppIcon = mAdapter.getIcons().get(mApps.get(i).getPackageName());
            // need to resize drawable here
            progressHandler.sendEmptyMessage(UPDATE_PBAR);
        }
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(DISMISS_PBAR);
    }

});

myThread.start();
```

Comment: which drawable you have to resize?

Comment: use  Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, dstWidth, dstHeight, filter)

Answer (score 81):

The following worked for me:

```
private Drawable resize(Drawable image) {
    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)image).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 50, 50, false);
    return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmapResized);
}
```

Comment: I got this error at fist line of code : java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.PictureDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

Comment: use a Drawable as argument and cast it to BitmapDrawable !? if your are sure that it's always a BitmapDrawable so change argument type to BitmapDrawable too, if not maybe it's nice to check drawable type before cast.

Answer (score 23):

Here's where I ended up, thanks in part to Saad's answer:

```
public Drawable scaleImage (Drawable image, float scaleFactor) {

    if ((image == null) || !(image instanceof BitmapDrawable)) {
        return image;
    }

    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)image).getBitmap();

    int sizeX = Math.round(image.getIntrinsicWidth() * scaleFactor);
    int sizeY = Math.round(image.getIntrinsicHeight() * scaleFactor);

    Bitmap bitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, sizeX, sizeY, false);

    image = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmapResized);

    return image;

}
```

Comment: perfect, this is the path i took.

Comment: Nice coding. Exactly what I needed. Thank you, brother :)

Comment: Be careful with this : the former drawable "image" contains a bitmap that has not been recycled. Calling "image = scaleImage(image, 2)" would cause a temporary leak.The caller of scaleImage thus has the responsibility to recycle both the original image and the scaled image... This may not be a problem in small apps but it is critical in memory-intensive apps.

Comment: @JMLord Good point, more on that here: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Comment: Any solutions or alternatives to this then that will avoid the memory leak

Comment: Great solution. Tested in Xamarin.Forms as well.

Answer (score 10):

For the resizing, this is nice and short (the code above wasn't working for me), found [here](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Images-In-Android/3/):

```
  ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
  Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.picture);
  Bitmap bMapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
  iv.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled);
```

Comment: This worked for when I wanted to resize the Drawable before set it as imageBitmap to an ImageView. Thx

Answer (score 8):

Here is a combination of the above answers as a Kotlin extension

```
fun Context.scaledDrawableResources(@DrawableRes id: Int, @DimenRes width: Int, @DimenRes height: Int): Drawable {
    val w = resources.getDimension(width).toInt()
    val h = resources.getDimension(height).toInt()
    return scaledDrawable(id, w, h)
}

fun Context.scaledDrawable(@DrawableRes id: Int, width: Int, height: Int): Drawable {
    val bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, id)
    val bmpScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, false)
    return BitmapDrawable(resources, bmpScaled)
}
```

Usage:

```
val scaled = context.scaledDrawableResources(R.drawable.ic_whatever, R.dimen.width, R.dimen.height)
imageView.setImageDrawable(scaled)
```

or

```
val scaled = context.scaledDrawable(R.drawable.ic_whatever, 100, 50)
imageView.setImageDrawable(scaled)
```

Comment: This one is great for fellow Kotliners!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my solution covers the question not completely, but I needed something like a "CustomDrawable".

In other words, I want to set a logo in front of a circle shape. So I created a FrameLayout with a background (just a colored circle) and in front of this round shape I show the logo.

**To resize the logo I shrink the logo by scaling** - here is some code:

```
iv = new ImageView(mContext);

iv.setScaleX(0.75f); // <- resized by scaling 
iv.setScaleY(0.75f);

// loading the drawable from a getter (replace this with any drawable)
Drawable drawable = ML.loadIcon(mContext, Integer.parseInt(icon));

iv.setImageDrawable(drawable);

// icon get's shown inside a ListView
viewHolder.mIvIcon.addView(iv);
```

Here is the FrameLayout which shows the icon inside ListView's row:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/iv_card_icon"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/circle"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    />
```

See this solution as an option / idea.

Answer (score 1):

The most voted answer wont work if the source Drawable is not instanceof BitmapDrawable which can be the case of using vector, color drawables, etc...

The most appropriate solution could be to draw the Drawable into a Canvas with set bitmap, as following:

```
@NonNull final Drawable drawable = yourSourceDrawable;

// Define the Canvas and Bitmap the drawable will be drawn against
final Canvas c = new Canvas();
c.setBitmap(bitmap);

// Draw the scaled drawable into the final bitmap
if (yourSourceDrawable!= null) {
    yourSourceDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    yourSourceDrawable.draw(c);
}
```

BONUS: To calculate the scale to be applied (e.g. when scaling the Drawable to a view):

```
if (drawable != null && drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() > 0 && drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() > 0) {
    // the intrinsic dimensions can be -1 in some cases such as ColorDrawables which aim to fill 
    // the whole View
    previewWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    previewHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
}

final float widthScale = mViewWidth / (float) (previewWidth);
if (widthScale != 1f)
    newWidth = Math.max((int)(widthScale * previewWidth), 1);

final float heightScale = mViewHeight / (float) (previewHeight);
if (heightScale != 1f)
    newHeight = Math.max((int)(heightScale * previewHeight), 1);
```

**NOTE: ALWAYS do this in a worker thread!**

Answer (score 1):

### Kotlin way

What it ended up working for me was this simple solution

```
fun resizeDrawable(width:Int, height:Int): Drawable {
        val drawable = ResourceUtils.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_info)
        val bitmap = drawable.toBitmap(width, height) //here width and height are in px
        return bitmap.toDrawable(getResources())
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with this issue, have in mind that the top rated answers here are not the way to go. Casting any Drawable to BitmapDrawable is not gonna work if the Drawable you have does not extend from BitmapDrawable, you'll get a ClassCastException instead.

This is the code I ended up using for resizing a Drawable which works for every kind of Drawable:

**Kotlin**

```
fun Context.getResizedDrawable(
    @DrawableRes drawableId: Int,
    @DimenRes size: Int,
): Drawable? {
    val dimen = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(size)

    return ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, drawableId)?.let { drawable ->
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dimen, dimen, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)

        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        drawable.draw(canvas)

        BitmapDrawable(this.resources, bitmap)
    }
}
```

**Java**

```
@Nullable
public Drawable getResizedDrawable(
    Context context,
    @DrawableRes int drawableId,
    @DimenRes int size
) {
    int dimen = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(size);
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dimen, dimen, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    if (drawable != null) {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);

        return new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```