# How to set size of context menu header icon?

Tags: android, android-layout, contextmenu, android-contextmenu

How can I set the size of the icon in the header of a context menu?

[image]

The icon is set via [ContextMenu.setHeaderIcon(int iconRes)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html#setHeaderIcon%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29).

Comment: Check the following:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021578/resize-drawable-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone else faces the same problem, I have eventually implemented it the following way.

I have written a generic method which takes a `Drawable` and the desired width and height as parameters. It returns a scaled `(Bitmap)Drawable` based on the given specs.

```
public Drawable getScaledIcon( Drawable drawable, int dstWidth, int dstHeight ) {

    Bitmap bitmap = ( (BitmapDrawable) drawable ).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( bitmap, dstWidth, dstHeight, false );

    return new BitmapDrawable( getResources(), bitmapScaled );
}
```

The method for setting the context menu header icon takes as a parameter either a resource ID via `ContextMenu.setHeaderIcon(int iconRes)` or a `Drawable` via `ContextMenu.setHeaderIcon(Drawable icon)`.

Use the latter in conjunction with `getScaledIcon(...)` and you're done! :)